# How can I add escaped \{ to the following regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building a Twig/Jinja template parser in JS, and need to match the following strings in JavaScript:

```
{%render "base"%}
{% render "base" with {"color":"red0xFF0000", "number": 123} %}
```

So far I have the following regex, as built in RegexBuddy:

```
\{% ?render *"[a-z0-9:._]+" ?((?:with +)({([^\{\}]*)}))? ?%}
```

This manages to match both render tags above, but, I want to allow escaped `\{` and `\}` to the body of the with `{...}` clause.

I've tried everything now, but can't get this working 100%. When I add a curly brace like so for example:

```
{% render "base" with {"color":"red\{0xFF0000\}", "number": 123} %}
```

The string doesn't match coz it terminates at the first `{` just past `red`.

Basically, I want the regex to match, but ignore `{` prefixed with `\`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use a negative lookahead: `(?!\\)` or an optional group: `(\\\})?`

Comment: I'm trying that, but not sure where to slip that in. :)

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't use regular expressions at all here. A proper token-by-token parser would be less complex (and possibly more efficient), IMHO.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing, burning too much gray matter over this one. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
{% ?render *"[a-z0-9:._]+" ?((?:with +)({[^{}\\]*(?:\\.[^{}\\]*)*}))? ?%}
```

The tricky part is this:

```
{[^{}\\]*(?:\\.[^{}\\]*)*}
```

After the opening brace, it matches zero or more of anything that's not a brace or a backslash - `[^{}\\]*`.  If it encounters a backslash, it consumes that and the next character - `\\.`.  It repeats that process as many times as necessary, until it reaches an unescaped closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

Could you convert the pertinent part to a lazy grab anything (.*?) ? < not part of the regex! < or that bit < or this .... etc.

```
{% ?render *"[a-z0-9:._]+" ?((?:with +)({(.*?)}))? ?%}
```